# How to remove duplicate x-axis labels in R

Tags: r, label, bar-chart, axis

I am trying to obtain a `barplot` representing mean percentage of coloration (`valores`) grouped both by sex and size intervals (`class`). However, labels in the x-axis appear duplicated. I would like to get one single label ("50-55" for the first and second columns together, "55-60" for the third and fourth columns together, and so on) for each `class` level. How could I do this?

Here is my code:

```
par(mar=c(7,4,4,2)+0.1)
class<-factor(coloration$clase.2,levels=c("50-55","55-60","60-65","65-70","70-75","75-80"))
sex<-factor(coloration$sexo,levels=c("M","H"))
valores<-coloration$perc.greenblue
graf<-barplot(tapply(valores,list(sex,class),mean),beside=T,axes=F,ylim=c(0,50),col=c(grey.colors(2)),axisnames=F ,xlab=("Sex and size"),ylab=("% mean coloration"),las=1)
axis(2,at=c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50),labels=c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50),las=1)
labs<-as.character(class)
text(graf,par("usr")[3]-0.25,srt=0,adj = c(0,2),labels=labs,xpd=T,cex=1)
legend(locator(1),c("Adult males","Adult females"),fill=c(grey.colors(2)),bty="n")
```

EDIT: here's some reproducible code:

```
structure(list(edad = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ADU", class = "factor"), 
    sexo = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("H", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    clase.2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
    6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("50-55", 
    "55-60", "60-65", "65-70", "70-75", "75-80"), class = "factor"), 
    perc.greenblue = c(0.09, 0.32, 12.8, 94.32, 34.83, 0.04, 
    45.83, 12.34, 0.75, 34.82, 0.5, 0.05, 3.46, 0, 1.72, 0.07, 
    0.09, 0.2)), row.names = c(9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 48L, 49L, 109L, 
110L, 194L, 195L, 263L, 264L, 266L, 267L, 332L, 333L, 408L, 409L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: could you use `dput` and provide example data from `coloration` (or `coloracion`) to make this more easily reproducible?

Comment: Hi @Ben, as the `dput` code was too long I inserted it on the question. Hope it helps and thank you!

Comment: If you use `axisnames = TRUE` in your `barplot` do you get the labels you want in the right location? (This is instead of using `text`).

Comment: Yes, it finally worked! Thank you so much!